# Accessing data base from admin gives errors

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

From a Firebase Function :

```
exports.contentServer = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var docRef = admin.firestore().collection('Brands').doc(name);
    return docRef.get()
    .then(function(snapshot) {
    var originalProduct = snapshot.products.find(o => o.productID === paymentMessage.item_number);
    //or
    var originalProduct = snapshot.val().products.find(o => o.productID === paymentMessage.item_number);
```

This document has a key `products` which is an `array`, where each element inside is an object.

**In the first case** it says that there is no `products` in `snapshot`.

**In the second case** it says that `snapshot.val()` is not a function.

How to access this `products` array ?

My data looks like :

```
Brands
  "products" : [{"productID":"xyz"},{}..]
```

Comment: I'm not really clear what you're expecting to happen here.  Please edit the question to show the full code of the function, as well as more complete description of the data you're trying to query.  We should be able to duplicate the issue based on what you provide.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks i edited the question but i am not sure what is the problem with it. I clearly show a code example, and the error i get. What i try to do? as I wrote clearly  - access a document and read an array inside of it (from admin). Please tell me what is not clear.

Comment: @paulseems I think you're mixing up the documentation for Realtime Databases and Cloud Firestore. Realtime Databases uses `.val()` while Cloud Firestore uses `.data()`. Does making this change fix your problem?

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth yes that's it, thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi! If you found the solution, could either of you post it as an answer? It will make it more visible for other users. Thanks!